# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Tags: error-message

I've run into this error from time to time:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS
```

I've seen it being thrown by several different files.  I don't know how to trigger it to better explain how to recreate the problem.

What does it mean?  What can I do to get it to disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing related to Craft at all, but a [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=424599#c23).  Has been fixed in v40 in the dev channel and will eventually make it into stable.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408931/bizarre-error-in-chrome-developer-console-failed-to-load-resource-neterr-ca

But I agree, it's a really annoying bug.